# How to use Constructor to create an object in python

Tags: python, class, constructor

This one has me very stuck. I need to use a class that I have created to create an object in the main module. However in my own experience we are supposed to create the object in main before we can call functions from a class.The name of the object i need to create will be named (Customer1), and the general idea of the program is that it is an ordering program for a Chinese restaurant The code is as follows.

```
def Choose_dish(self):

    print('Please choose from the following items for a main dish:'
          'Sweet and Sour Pork, Sesame Chicken, or Shrimp Fried rice.')

    choice = input('Press 1 for Sweet and Sour, Press 2 for Sesame Chicken, or press 3 for Shrimp Fried rice.')

    if choice == 1:
        self._dish = 'sweet and sour'

    if choice ==2:
        self._dish = 'sesame chicken'

    if choice == 3:
        self._dish = 'shrimp fried rice'
```

The first method is the protected constructor which is meant to be called so the (Customer1) object can select a choice of main dish. The following is the code I have been trying in main.

```
from Dinner_Combo import Dinner_combo
def main():
    print('Welcome to the restaurant')
    choice = input('please select 1 for regular meal, or select 2 for deluxe meal!')
    if int(choice) == 1:
        customer1 = Dinner_combo()

main()
```

please note that the name of the python class file I have created is  "Dinner_Combo", and the name of the class itself is "Dinner_combo"

Comment: You have broken indentation. Please fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Dinner_combo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._dish = self.Choose_dish()

    def Choose_dish(self):
        print('Please choose from the following items for a main dish:'
              'Sweet and Sour Pork, Sesame Chicken, or Shrimp Fried rice.')
        choice = input('Press 1 for Sweet and Sour, Press 2 for Sesame Chicken, or press 3 for Shrimp Fried rice.')
        if choice == 1:
            return 'sweet and sour'
        elif choice == 2:
            return 'sesame chicken'
        elif choice == 3:
            return 'shrimp fried rice'
```

The above should help you achieve the desired behavior in the `main` but I would suggest that you re-asses your approach: I generally try to avoid any kind of operations that could crash in the initializer.

---

Initializer (`__init__(self, ...)`) is a special method of a class that is called "automatically" after the object is created. The object actually already exists and the initializer simply initializes it. Usually, you do not call it explicitly unless you call it to initialize the parent class.

From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects:

> The instantiation operation (“calling” a class object) creates an empty object. Many classes like to create objects with instances customized to a specific initial state. Therefore a class may define a special method named `__init__()`, like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data = []
```

> When a class defines an `__init__()` method, class instantiation automatically invokes `__init__()` for the newly-created class instance.